# Minimum of a sum over the simplex

Tags: probability, combinatorics, discrete-mathematics, optimization, simplex

**Setup**: I was trying to simplify the following minimization problem

$$\min\limits_{x\in\mathcal{X}}\left\{\mathbb{E}\left[\max\limits_{k\in[m]}\left\{s_k \sum\limits_{i=1}^n \xi_i x_i\right\}\right]\right\}$$
where $\xi_i\sim$ Exp$(i)$, $s_k\geq 0$ are known constants, and $\mathcal{X}$ denotes the simplex in $\mathbb{R}^n$. I was able to reduce the problem to the following
$$\min\limits_{x\in\mathcal{X}}\left\{\left(\sum\limits_{i=1}^n ix_i\right)^{-1}\sum\limits_{\mathcal{K}\in\mathcal{P}[m]} (-1)^{|\mathcal{K}|-1}\left(\sum\limits_{k\in\mathcal{K}} s_k\right)^{-1}\right\}$$
$$=\min\limits_{x\in\mathcal{X}}\left\{\left(\sum\limits_{i=1}^n ix_i\right)^{-1}S\right\}$$

where $\mathcal{P}[m]$ denotes the powerset of the set of the first $m$ natural numbers excluding the empty set and $S$ denotes the sum over the terms in the powerset.

**Question**: If $s_k=k$, then $S>0$ (by numerically checking) implying $x^*=e_n$ (and if $S<0$, we take $x^*=e_1$) trivially, but is there a general, simple combinatorial argument to see if this sum, $S$, is positive/negative based on our choice of $\{s_k\}$ or no?

**Source**: I read [this](https://www2.isye.gatech.edu/%7Enemirovs/SIOPT_RSA_2009.pdf) paper by Nemirovski and Juditsky on a similar stochastic utility problem, and thought that instead of i.i.d normals, independent exponentials with varying rates and no shifts would make for a slightly less trivial problem to optimize.

Comment: I might be mistaken, but it seems at first sight that the expectation and the maximum operators might commute in that case.

Comment: I don't think this is necessarily the case here as the maximum of the expectation of these exponentials will be given by the maximum of some rates, but not equivalent to the sum I gave above when we actually compute the distribution of the maximum. I could flesh out the work in between if you want